# Is there any module like single-login for Drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to restrict users to login into my site only once at a time from different browsers. For this, there is the Single Login module in Drupal 6, but it is not available for Drupal 7.

Is there any alternative for this module for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue on Drupal website for [Single Login](http://drupal.org/project/single_login) module, check it [here](http://drupal.org/node/1220164).

As alternative to Single Login module, try:

- [Session Limit](http://drupal.org/project/session_limit)
- [Automated Logout](http://drupal.org/project/autologout)

Comment: I tried this session-limit module,but the problem here it is when the browser closed the session is not closed.

Comment: @pradeep you need to set `session.cookie_lifetime` to 0 in settings.php. By default its 2000000 which represent 23 days.